# Error in loading Data from SSIS errorlog table to a SQL Server table

Tags: c#, sql-server, logging, error-handling, ssis

I have created Logging under SSIS and it's generated in the system table of my database as `[dbo].[sysssislog]`. I am trying to get specific columns like Id, Source, starttime, endtime and message to another SQL Server table, client.EximLog and `Client.EximLogHistory`.

Every time I run the package it's throws following error:

> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action1 wrapCloseInAction)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action1 wrapCloseInAction)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
>      at ScriptMain.Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
>      at UserComponent.Input0_ProcessInput(Input0Buffer Buffer)
>      at UserComponent.ProcessInput(Int32 InputID, String InputName, PipelineBuffer Buffer, OutputNameMap OutputMap)
>      at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ScriptComponent.ProcessInput(Int32 InputID, PipelineBuffer buffer)
>      at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ScriptComponentHost.ProcessInput(Int32 inputID, PipelineBuffer buffer)

I have created a event handler 'Onerror' to execute a dataflow task, say 'Connect to SSIS Log Table'.

In the dataflow task, I am connecting to the sysssislog table using a OLD DB Connection.

```
SELECT Id, source, starttime, endtime, message 
FROM dbo.sysssislog
WHERE event = 'onerror' AND ID NOT IN (SELECT ISNULL(cast(LogId as int), 0)  FROM [Client].[EximLog])
```

I have connected the OLD DB source connection to Script component as Destination. I am Executing the following stored procedure.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spEximLog]
--Add parameters for the stored procedure
    @pSystemID nvarchar(max) = NULL,
    --@sEvent nvarchar(max) = NULL,
    @pSource nvarchar(max) = NULL,
    @pStarttime nvarchar(max) = NULL,
    @pEndtime nvarchar(max) = NULL,
    @pMessage nvarchar(max) = NULL
    WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @vJoboutcome nvarchar(max);
    DECLARE @vGUID nvarchar(40);
    DECLARE @vTimeStamp timestamp;
    DECLARE @vEximID int;
    DECLARE @vDefaultOperation nvarchar(40);
    DECLARE @vDefaultEventRegistrationId int;
    DECLARE @vDefaultVersion int;

    SET @vJoboutcome = 'F';
    SET @vDefaultOperation = 'Insert';
    SET @vDefaultEventRegistrationId = 1;
    SET @vDefaultVersion = 1;


    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[sysssislog] WHERE ID = @pSystemID)

    BEGIN

        SET @vGUID = CAST((SELECT NEWID()) as nvarchar(40));

        --Inserting 8 cloumns into Exim table
        INSERT INTO [Client].[EXIMLog]
        (
          [JobName], [JobMessage], [JobOutCome], [LogID], [DtmJobStart], [DtmJobEnd]
        , [EventRegistrationId], [ObjectId]
        )

        VALUES(@pSource, @pMessage, @vJoboutcome, @pSystemID, @pStarttime, @pEndtime
        , @vDefaultEventRegistrationId, @vGUID);

        SET @vEximID = (SELECT @@IDENTITY); /*Same EximId is used in Malvern import and in its history table*/

        --Stores the timestamp for the row using where clause
        SET @vTimeStamp = (SELECT [TimeStamp] from [Client].[EXIMLog] where Id = @vEximId);


        --Inserting 12 cloumns into Exim History table
        INSERT INTO [Client].[EXIMLogHistory]
        (
          [Id], [Version], [JobName], [JobMessage], [JobOutCome], [LogID], [DtmJobStart]
        , [DtmJobEnd], [EventRegistrationId], [ObjectId], [Operation], [TimeStamp]
        )
        VALUES(@vEximID, @vDefaultVersion, @pSource, @pMessage, @vJoboutcome, @pSystemID,  @pStarttime, @pEndtime, @vDefaultEventRegistrationId, @vGUID
        , @vDefaultOperation, CAST(@vTimeStamp as varbinary));
    END
END;
GO
```

Following is the script I am using in the Script Component and the connection manager is an ADO.net Connection.

```
#region Namespaces
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper;
#endregion
```

---

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn =
        (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection)Connections.SecondConnection.AcquireConnection(null);
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("Exec [dbo].[spEximLog]'" + Row.Id + "', '" + Row.source + "', '" + Row.starttime +"', '" + Row.endtime + "' , '" + Row.message + "'", conn);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: The "error" you posted isn't the error message.   it's the stack trace.   Look again and see if you can find the actual error.

Comment: I found out that 'message' column has a word 'spEximlog' in single quotes. So changed the way of passing the script as follows and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Changed the script component code as follows and solved the problem.

```
public override void PostExecute()
    {
        base.PostExecute();

        conn.Close();

    }
```

---

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
    {
        if(conn.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            conn.Open();
        }
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("[dbo].[spEximLog]", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@pSystemID", Row.Id));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@pSource", Row.source));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@pstarttime", Row.starttime));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@pendtime", Row.endtime));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@pmessage", Row.message));

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

Independently assigned the parameters. Closed the connection in the post execute so that it doesn't reach maximum connection pooling.